# devexpress wpf dateEdit default selection cursor problem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYFhM.png)
I'm using the GotFocus event on the WPF frontend which automatically assigns a value when I click on it. But my DateTime control will automatically select the cursor based on where I click. I want it to keep selecting the first one.
This is my Xaml code

```
<dxe:DateEdit x:Name="_dateEdit"
            EditValue="{Binding Time,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                      NullText="{Binding StrNullText,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                      Style="{Binding TimeStyle,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                      PopupOpening="DateEdit_PopupOpening"
                      GotFocus="DateEdit_GotFocus"
                      EditValueChanged="DateEdit_EditValueChanged">
            <dxe:ButtonInfo x:Name="_dateEditButtonInfo" Tag="{Binding TimeTag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" IsDefaultButton="True"/>
        </dxe:DateEdit>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPNQV.gif)

```
private void DateEdit_PopupOpening(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.OpenPopupEventArgs e)
{
    if (Time.HasValue)
    {
        return;
    }
    Time = DateTime.Now;
}

private void DateEdit_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dateEdit = sender as DateEdit;
    if (Time.HasValue)
    {
        return;
    }
    Time = DateTime.Now;

    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        //Attempted unsuccessful cases
        Task.Delay(10000); 
        //dateEdit.Select(0, 2);
        _dateEdit.SelectionStart = 0;
        _dateEdit.SelectionLength = 0;
    });
}
```

I tried the Select(0, 2) method and
specified
dateEdit.SelectionStart = 0;
dateEdit.SelectionLength = 2;
all failed
The correct thing is that no matter where I click, it will be displayed like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJxXW.png)

Comment: Welcome everyone to discuss